# Why should we use the “extends” keyword but not the type itself?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I've read this article https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints

I'm wondering that why we have to use the `extends` keyword here?

```
interface Lengthwise {
  length: number;
}

function loggingIdentity<T extends Lengthwise>(arg: T): T {
  console.log(arg.length); // Now we know it has a .length property, so no more error
  return arg;
}
```

Why not just do it like this?? What's the difference when I use the `extends` keyword?

```
interface Lengthwise {
  length: number;
}

function loggingIdentity(arg: Lengthwise): Lengthwise {
  console.log(arg.length); // Now we know it has a .length property, so no more error
  return arg;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

It's not like you *always* have to do that. It just happens to be what you want, most of the time.

When you do this:

```
function loggingIdentity<T extends Lengthwise>(arg: T): T {
```

then `loggingIdentity` will return exactly the same subtype of `T` as it accepted. This is a stronger promise than saying:

```
function loggingIdentity(arg: Lengthwise): Lengthwise {
```

which only promises to return a `Lengthwise`, which doesn't have to match the accepted parameter.

Let me illustrate the point.

```
interface Lengthwise {
  length: number;
}

declare function generic<T extends Lengthwise>(arg: T): T;
declare function concrete(arg: Lengthwise): Lengthwise;

const myArgument = { length: 1, foo: 'bar '};

const first = generic(myArgument).foo; // string
const second = concrete(myArgument).foo; // Compile-time error — the knowledge of `foo` was lost
```

As you can see, `second` has no property called `foo` on it. `concrete` only promises to return a `Lengthwise`, not the exact subtype of `Lengthwise` provided to it.

Answer (score 0):

- the difference is by using `extends` it means that  the generic or whatever is extended can inherit all properties from the interface and add more properties but in the second case you can't add more than `length` property in the interface. so u can't add more than one property which here is the `length` property but by using `extends` you can use as many arguments as you wish beside the properties of the interface.